# NopCommerce attempted SQL injection?

Tags: c#, sql-injection

I tried to post this on the NopCommerce boards, but it blocked me.  So, I'm guessing this might be dangerous?  Anyway, here is my attempted post:

I've had a number of searches in my store recently which appear to be hacks or data manipulation attempts.  Should I be concerned about these?

Below are a few examples:

```
http://www.example.com
<"hdpnvb >
<<<<"hdpnvb >>>
MK%!08x!MK
MK%08xMK
|| sleep 3 &
|| ping -n 5 127.0.0.1 &
|| ping -n 3 127.0.0.1 &
(and several variants of the two above)
; x || sleep 5 &
; x || sleep 3 &
../admin/noop.cgi?foo=bar
../../../../../../../../../../writetest1663380092.txt
" onfocus="alert(502)
```

Can anyone with better knowledge of C# or web technology tell me what the user(s) was/were trying to accomplish?  Is there some kind of vulnerability that this application might be subject to?  I understand a little about SQL injection, and these appear to me to be attempts at it.

Comment: None of these are specifically SQL vulnerabilities. There's a mix of LFI and XSS (first one) and a mish-mash of RCE type stuff.

Local File Inclusion, Cross Site Scripting, and Remote Code Execution

Comment: If you know, can you explain what they were trying to accomplish and whether I should be alarmed?  Were they trying to gain control of the site?  Shut down the server?  Insert a virus?

Comment: It's just some random attempts to find possible vulnerabilities. There's no guarantee your server is vulnerable (or safe for that matter). Each vulnerability is different in terms of possible damages, but you should 100% be fine unless you're on an outdated version of NC.